# In SparkSQL how could I select a subset of columns from a nested struct and keep it as a nested struct in the result using SQL statement?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I can do the following statement in SparkSQL:

```
result_df = spark.sql("""select
    one_field,
    field_with_struct
  from purchases""")
```

And resulting data frame will have the field with full struct in `field_with_struct`.

| one_field | field_with_struct |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | {name1,val1,val2,f2,f4} |
| 555 | {name2,val3,val4,f6,f7} |

I want to select only few fields from `field_with_struct`, but keep them still in struct in the resulting data frame. If something could be possible (this is not real code):

```
result_df = spark.sql("""select
    one_field,
    struct(
      field_with_struct.name,
      field_with_struct.value2
    ) as my_subset
  from purchases""")
```

To get this:

| one_field | my_subset |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | {name1,val2} |
| 555 | {name2,val4} |

Is there any way of doing this with SQL? (not with fluent API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the pseudo code which I have provided is working. For a nested array of object it's not so straightforward. At first, the array should be exploded (EXPLODE() function) and then selected a subset. After that it's possible to make a COLLECT_LIST().

```
WITH
  unfold_by_items AS (SELECT id, EXPLODE(Items) AS item FROM spark_tbl_items)
, format_items as (SELECT
    id
    , STRUCT(
              item.item_id
            , item.name
        ) AS item
    FROM unfold_by_items)
, fold_by_items AS (SELECT id, COLLECT_LIST(item) AS Items FROM format_items GROUP BY id)

SELECT * FROM fold_by_items
```

This will choose only two fields from the struct in Items and in the end returns a dataset which contains again an array with Items.

Answer (score 6):

There's a much simpler solution making use of [arrays_zip](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip.html), no need to explode/collect_list (which can be error prone/difficult with complex data since it relies on using something like an id column):

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import arrays_zip
>>> df = sc.createDataFrame((([Row(x=1, y=2, z=3), Row(x=2, y=3, z=4)],),), ['array_of_structs'])
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+----------------------+
|array_of_structs      |
+----------------------+
|[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}]|
+----------------------+
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- array_of_structs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z: long (nullable = true)
>>> # Selecting only two of the nested fields:
>>> selected_df = df.select(arrays_zip("array_of_structs.x", "array_of_structs.y").alias("array_of_structs"))
>>> selected_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- array_of_structs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)
>>> selected_df.show()
+----------------+
|array_of_structs|
+----------------+
|[{1, 2}, {2, 3}]|
+----------------+
```

**EDIT** Adding in the corresponding Spark SQL code, since that was requested by the OP:

```py
>>> df.createTempView("test_table")
>>> sql_df = sc.sql("""
SELECT
transform(array_of_structs, x -> struct(x.x, x.y)) as array_of_structs
FROM test_table
""")
>>> sql_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- array_of_structs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)
>>> sql_df.show()
+----------------+
|array_of_structs|
+----------------+
|[{1, 2}, {2, 3}]|
+----------------+
```